# Calculating Divergence of $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I have a vector field $F = (x,y,z)$ where $(x,y,z)$ is not equal to $(0,0,0)$. I must calculate the divergence of $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$ where $r$ is the magnitude of $\vec{r}$.

All I did was calculate divergence$(\frac{(x,y,z)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}$).

I did this and simplified to obtain $\frac{2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}$ which is $\frac{2}{r}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There are multiple ways to get the answer. If both ways give you the same answer, its probably right.

Consider, $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}=\hat r=1\hat r$

Since the divergence is a scalar, it has the same value in different coordinate systems.

In spherical coordinates, $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial r} (r^2E_r)}{r^2}$ if the vector $\vec{E}$ only has a radial component.

In this case, $E_r=1$, so the result is indeed $\frac{2}{r}$

Alternatively, $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}=\hat{r}= \nabla r$

By definition $\nabla ^2V = \nabla \cdot \nabla V. $

So $\nabla \cdot \hat{r} = \nabla ^2 r$

The Laplacian is also a scalar.

The Laplacian for only raidal dependence is $\nabla ^2 V = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial V}{\partial r})=\frac{2}{r}$

These approaches have the added advantage of avoiding a complicated derivative of a quotient you probably executed when solving the problem in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, I like that method.